# docker container runnig out of space

Tags: docker, centos, overlay, docker-image

I setup a docker image for yocto compiling but running out of space after 30% of bitbaking. Host system is Centos 7.

```
[root@localhost emil]# df -h
Dateisystem             Größe Benutzt Verf. Verw% Eingehängt auf
/dev/mapper/centos-root   50G     50G  120M  100% /
/dev/nvme0n1p6          1014M    222M  793M   22% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1           200M     37M  164M   19% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/centos-home  241G    207G   34G   87% /home
/dev/sdb1                917G    219G  652G   26% /mnt/data
tmpfs                    1.6G     60K  1.6G    1% /run/user/0
overlay                   50G     50G  120M  100% /mnt/docker-data/overlay2/9f4035a717fb22aeffe7e0291a37608a73969cdcaaf536da5828a57e0431864f/merged
```

**/etc/docker/daemon.json**

```
{
        "exec-root":"/mnt/docker-run",
        "data-root": "/mnt/docker-data",
        "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
```

**/etc/fstab**

```
/dev/mapper/centos-root  /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/centos-home  /home                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper              /centos-swap swap       swap    defaults        0 0
/dev/sdb1                /mnt/data               ext4    defaults        0 0
```

How can I setup docker to run the docker container on /mnt/data/....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the directory on the mount:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/data/docker-data
```

Create or edit your `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and add set the following option(official documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file)):

```
{
  "data-root": "/mnt/data/docker-data"
}
```

Reload and restart the docker daemon:

```
systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: Already did this, see /etc/docker/daemon.json output above. But I had /mnt/docker-data instead of /mnt/data/docker-data.

Comment: But I think this was the issue. compiling now (20%) and no noticable disk use  on /dev/mapper/centos-root, only /mnt/data.